# Need help with solution for problem A5 from IMO 2015

Tags: contest-math

I'm going through solution for A5 from International Mathematical Olympiad 2015. Something's not right. Here's how it goes:

First, we assume all functions below map integers to integers.

Second, for any function $g$ and any nonzero integer $t$ we introduce an operator
$$
\Delta_tg(x)=g(x+t)-g(x).
$$

Third, we are given some very specific function $f$ and for all $x,a\in\mathbb{Z}$ we establish
$$
\Delta_{f(x)}f(a)=\Delta_{f(x)}f(2x-a-f(x)).
$$

Here's where it gets troublesome. They successively apply this last expression to every $a = b, b+f(x),\dots,b+(k-1)f(x)$, where $b,k$ are arbitrary positive integers, and then sum them up. Summing them up gives them
$$
\Delta_{kf(x)}f(b)=\Delta_{kf(x)}f(2x-b-kf(x)).
$$
Which I can't repeat. Instead I'm getting
$$
\Delta_{kf(x)}f(b)=\Delta_{kf(x)}f(2x-b-f(x)).
$$
Here's how I derive it for $k=2$. Left side:
$$
\Delta_{f(x)}f(b)+\Delta_{f(x)}f(b+f(x))=
$$
$$
=f(b+f(x))-f(b)+f(b+2f(x))-f(b+f(x))=
$$
$$
=f(b+2f(x))-f(b)=\Delta_{2f(x)}f(b).
$$
Right side:
$$
\Delta_{f(x)}f(2x-b-f(x))+\Delta_{f(x)}f(2x-b-2f(x))=
$$
$$
=f(2x-b-2f(x))-f(2x-b-f(x))+f(2x-b-3f(x))-f(2x-b-2f(x))=
$$
$$
=f(2x-b-3f(x))-f(2x-b-f(x))=\Delta_{2f(x)}f(2x-b-f(x)).
$$
I can't believe they made an error in official solutions, but I don't see any in mine either. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What is the IMO question?

Comment: International Mathematical Olympiad.

Comment: You should state the original question in your post.  The post should be self contained, people shouldn't have to look up the question.

Comment: I know what IMO means. What is the question from the IMO? You give an outline of the answer, but it helps to have the question and the complete answer.

Comment: I provided everything one would need to deal with the kind of problem I'm having. But here's the official PDF: https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2015SL.pdf Problem A5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}\left(\Delta_{kf(x)}f\right)(b)&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\Delta_{f(x)}f\right)(b+jf(x))\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\Delta_{f(x)}f\right)(2x-b-jf(x)-f(x))\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\Delta_{f(x)}f\right)\left(2x-b-kf(x)+(k-j-1)f(x)\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(\Delta_{f(x)}f\right)\left(2x-b-kf(x)+if(x)\right)\\
&=\left(\Delta_{kf(x)}f\right)\left(2x-b-kf(x)\right)
\end{align}$$

where $i=k-1-j$ in the substitution.

Your error is in calculating the right side values. The correct values are:

$$\begin{align}\left(\Delta_{f(x)}f\right)\left(2x-b-f(x)\right)&=f\left(2x-b\right)-f\left(2x-b-f(x)\right)\\
\left(\Delta_{f(x)}f\right)\left(2x-b-2f(x)\right)&=\left(2x-b-f(x)\right)-\left(2x-b-2f(x)\right)
\end{align}$$

And you see the add up to $\left(\Delta_{f(x)}f\right)(2x-b-2f(x)).$

In your calculation, you're using that $\Delta_t f(x)=f(x-t)-f(x)$, which is both the wrong direction and the wrong order.

Comment: Oh, boy... Sorry for wasting your time. I subtracted $t$ instead of adding it, indeed. What confused me was that there is $f(b)$ on the left side, so I somehow led myself to believe that $b$ is sort of an argument, so $b$ should be changed for $b+f(x)$ on the right as well, leading to $-b-f(x)$ under $f$ and eventually to my wrong end-result. Thanks a lot.